# Análisis de listas CSV Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista, csv

Converti un csv en lista:

```
a = [['Cliente', 'Fecha', 'Variables', 'Dia Previo', 'Mayor/Menor', 'Dia a Analizar', 'Analisis'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '0.41', 'Dentro del Margen', '0.35', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '2.25', 'Dentro del Margen', '2.7', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '62.4', 'Dentro del Margen', '61.21', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '153927.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '173663.0', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Subastas', '6827946.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '6431093.0', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '1.06', 'Dentro del Margen', '1.06', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '26.67', 'Dentro del Margen', '27.2', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '11.34', 'Dentro del Margen', '12.77', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '10648.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '12099.0', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Subastas', '39930.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '44479.0', 'Estable'],
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '0.41', 'Dentro del Margen', '0.35', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '2.25', 'Dentro del Margen', '2.7', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '62.4', 'Dentro del Margen', '61.21', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '153927.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '173663.0', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Subastas', '6827946.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '6431093.0', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '1.06', 'Dentro del Margen', '1.06', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '26.67', 'Dentro del Margen', '27.2', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '11.34', 'Dentro del Margen', '12.77', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '10648.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '12099.0', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Subastas', '39930.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '44479.0', 'Estable']]
```

Necesito analizar la información de esa lista donde se analice por grupos de clientes y fechas primero como `cliente AAA en el 27/12/2017, AAA en el 28/12/2017, BBB en el 27/12/2017, BBB en el 28/12/2017, CCC en el 27/12/2017, CCC en el 28/12/2017` y dentro de cada uno de esos grupos se tome en cuenta el `Analisis` (`Estable Alerta o Incremento` que son las 3 variables que pueden presentar) en este caso si para el cliente AAA el 27/12/2017 todos los valores de Analisis fueron Estable, quiero que en el nuevo archivo csv aparezca: `AAA, 27/12/2017, El rendimiento del cliente fue Estable` y así sucesivamente para cada cliente y fecha!

Necesito alguna función que sea con condicionales donde por cada lista que el cliente y la fecha sean iguales analizar la columna de `Analisis` y segun esta si son todas `Estable`, `AAA, 27/12/2017, Estable: El rendimiento del cliente fue Estable` y si no `AAA, 27/12/2017, NoAnalizada`

Comment: ¿y si no son iguales? si tu pregunta es *Es posible?*, la respuesta es que sí, alguna otra pregunta. Con lo anterior quiero decirte que mejores tu pregunta ademas de mostrar lo que has intentado.

Comment: editada! Gracias @eyllanesc

Comment: Ya he visto varias de tus preguntas, siempre pides cosas pero no veo que intentas solucionar tu problema, esfuerzate. ¿Esperas que hagamos tu trabajo?

Comment: Llevo hojas y hojas intentándolo en papel y en sublime pero no logro crear algo concreto para poner en la pregunta sino lo haría. Fíjate todas mis preguntas y mas del 90% tienen intentos de redacción de código. No todos sabemos como vos el lenguaje. @eyllanesc

Comment: Yo no digo que no intentes, lo que te pido es que muestres lo que has intentado para iniciar desde ese punto, asi ganamos los 2, nosotros ganamos porque no iniciamos desde cero, y tu ganas porque veras cuales fueron tus errores, esa es la dinamica de SO.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128290/análisis-data-por-grupos-csv-python @eyllanesc ahi hice la pregunta mejor redactada y con parte del código. Podes ayudarme?