# Análisis data por grupos CSV Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, lista

Convierto un csv en una lista llamada a. Cree a travez de un condicional una forma de clasificar mi data. El problema es que no esta funcionando. Si hay un elemento cualquiera llamado `'Estable'` a todos mis elementos me coloca el condicional de `'Estable'` lo cual no es lo que necesito sino que para todos los clientes que no tengan `'Estable'` como `AAA` y `BBB` quiero que coloque 'NoAnalyzed' tal y como explico abajo del código.

```
import pandas as pd



a = [['Cliente', 'Fecha', 'Variables', 'Dia Previo', 'Mayor/Menor', 'Dia a Analizar', 'Analisis'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '0.41', 'Dentro del Margen', '0.35', 'Incremento'],
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '1.06', 'Dentro del Margen', '1.06', 'Alerta'],
['CCC', '27/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '1.06', 'Dentro del Margen', '1.06', 'Estable']]



headers = a.pop(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns = headers)
df['Analisis']


for elemento in df['Analisis']:
    if elemento == 'Estable':
        df['Status'] = 'Stable: The client''s performance was Stable'
    else:
        df['Status'] = 'NoAnalyzed'


df1= df.groupby(['Cliente','Fecha', 'Status']).size()
df1

output:
>>>
Cliente  Fecha       Status                                    
AAA      27/12/2017  Stable: The clients performance was Stable    1
BBB      27/12/2017  Stable: The clients performance was Stable    1
CCC      27/12/2017  Stable: The clients performance was Stable    1

Lo que necesito:
>>>
Cliente  Fecha       Status                                    
AAA      27/12/2017  NoAnalyzed    1
BBB      27/12/2017  NoAnalyzed    1
CCC      27/12/2017  Stable: The clients performance was Stable    1
```

**Edición:**

Aplicando la solución de la respuesta de FJSevilla sobre un conjunto más extenso:

```
a = [['Cliente', 'Fecha', 'Variables', 'Dia Previo', 'Mayor/Menor', 'Dia a Analizar', 'Analisis'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '0.41', 'Dentro del Margen', '0.35', 'Alerta'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '2.25', 'Dentro del Margen', '2.7', 'Incremento'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '62.4', 'Dentro del Margen', '61.21', 'Incremento'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '153927.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '173663.0', 'Incremento'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Subastas', '6827946.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '6431093.0', 'Incremento'], 
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '1.06', 'Dentro del Margen', '1.06', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '26.67', 'Dentro del Margen', '27.2', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '11.34', 'Dentro del Margen', '12.77', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '10648.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '12099.0', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Subastas', '39930.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '44479.0', 'Estable'],
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '0.41', 'Dentro del Margen', '0.35', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '2.25', 'Dentro del Margen', '2.7', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '62.4', 'Dentro del Margen', '61.21', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '153927.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '173663.0', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Subastas', '6827946.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '6431093.0', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '1.06', 'Dentro del Margen', '1.06', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '26.67', 'Dentro del Margen', '27.2', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '11.34', 'Dentro del Margen', '12.77', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '10648.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '12099.0', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Subastas', '39930.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '44479.0', 'Estable']]


headers = a.pop(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns = headers)

df["Status"] = np.where(df['Analisis'] == "Estable",
                        'Stable: The clients performance was Stable',
                        'NoAnalyzed')
df1= df.groupby(['Cliente','Fecha', 'Status']).size()
df1
```

La salida es:

```
>>> df1
Cliente  Fecha       Status                                    
AAA      27/12/2017  NoAnalyzed                                    5
         28/12/2017  Stable: The clients performance was Stable    5
BBB      27/12/2017  Stable: The clients performance was Stable    5
         28/12/2017  Stable: The clients performance was Stable    5
dtype: int64
```

Si tuviera que decir por ejemplo, el caso `AAA`:

```
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '0.41', 'Dentro del Margen', '0.35', 'Alerta'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '2.25', 'Dentro del Margen', '2.7', 'Incremento'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '62.4', 'Dentro del Margen', '61.21', 'Incremento'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '153927.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '173663.0', 'Incremento'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Subastas', '6827946.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '6431093.0', 'Incremento'].
```

En este caso fijate que la columna `Analisis`varia entre Incremento y Alerta. Quiero que analice si en `ECPM_medio = 'Alerta'`, `Fill_rate = 'Incremento'`, `'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio' = 'Incremento'`, `Impresiones_exchange = 'Incremento'`y `'Subastas' = 'Incremento'`----> `df["Status"] = "Critico"`

¿Cómo puedo hacer eso? ¿Dar ciertos condicionales por cada variable que tiene el cliente en dicha fecha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que cuando haces `df['Status'] = ...` el cambio se aplica a **toda la columna**, todas las filas tendrán el valor que les des. Como  en tu caso el último valor que asignas es `'Stable: The client''s performance was Stable'` este es el valor que tiene todas tus columnas.

Hay varias formas de hacer esto, como usar `pandas.DataFrame.apply`, pero una muy simple es `numpy.where`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



a = [['Cliente', 'Fecha', 'Variables', 'Dia Previo', 'Mayor/Menor', 'Dia a Analizar', 'Analisis'],
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '0.41', 'Dentro del Margen', '0.35', 'Incremento'],
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '1.06', 'Dentro del Margen', '1.06', 'Alerta'],
['CCC', '27/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '1.06', 'Dentro del Margen', '1.06', 'Estable']]



headers = a.pop(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns = headers)

df["Status"] = np.where(df['Analisis'] == "Estable",
                        'Stable: The clients performance was Stable',
                        'NoAnalyzed')
df1= df.groupby(['Cliente','Fecha', 'Status']).size()
```

La salida es:

```
>>> df1
Cliente  Fecha       Status                                    
AAA      27/12/2017  NoAnalyzed                                    1
BBB      27/12/2017  NoAnalyzed                                    1
CCC      27/12/2017  Stable: The clients performance was Stable    1
dtype: int64
```

---

**Edición:**

Si quieres obtener un resultado distinto para cada grupo cliente-fecha puedes usar una idea parecida  la que muestras inicialmente, con una función Python pero usando [`pandas.DataFrame.aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) para aplicarla a cada grupo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


a = [['Cliente', 'Fecha', 'Variables', 'Dia Previo', 'Mayor/Menor', 'Dia a Analizar', 'Analisis'],
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '0.41', 'Dentro del Margen', '0.35', 'Alerta'],
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '2.25', 'Dentro del Margen', '2.7', 'Incremento'],
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '62.4', 'Dentro del Margen', '61.21', 'Incremento'],
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '153927.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '173663.0', 'Incremento'],
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Subastas', '6827946.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '6431093.0', 'Incremento'],
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '1.06', 'Dentro del Margen', '1.06', 'Estable'],
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '26.67', 'Dentro del Margen', '27.2', 'Estable'],
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '11.34', 'Dentro del Margen', '12.77', 'Estable'],
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '10648.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '12099.0', 'Estable'],
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Subastas', '39930.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '44479.0', 'Estable'],
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '0.41', 'Dentro del Margen', '0.35', 'Estable'],
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '2.25', 'Dentro del Margen', '2.7', 'Estable'],
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '62.4', 'Dentro del Margen', '61.21', 'Estable'],
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '153927.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '173663.0', 'Estable'],
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Subastas', '6827946.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '6431093.0', 'Estable'],
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '1.06', 'Dentro del Margen', '1.06', 'Estable'],
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '26.67', 'Dentro del Margen', '27.2', 'Estable'],
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '11.34', 'Dentro del Margen', '12.77', 'Estable'],
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '10648.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '12099.0', 'Estable'],
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Subastas', '39930.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '44479.0', 'Estable']]


def status(group):
    condiciones = (np.array_equal(group, ("Estable", "Estable", "Estable", "Estable", "Estable")),
                   np.array_equal(group, ("Alerta", "Incremento", "Incremento", "Incremento", "Incremento")))
    resultados = ("Estable", "Crítico")
    return np.select(condiciones, resultados, default="Undetermined")

headers = a.pop(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=headers)
df1 = df.groupby(['Cliente', 'Fecha'])["Analisis"].aggregate([('Status', status)])
```

La salida es:

```
>>> df1
                     Status
Cliente Fecha              
AAA     27/12/2017  Crítico
        28/12/2017  Estable
BBB     27/12/2017  Estable
        28/12/2017  Estable
```

En vez de recurrir a una estructura condicional normal como haces tú he recurrido a `numpy.equal` para comparar la columna `Analisis` de cada grupo con los valores posibles cuya coincidencia quieres evaluar junto a [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) para asignar cada condición a la cadena de salida apropiada. `condiciones` es el iterable que almacena cada condición a evaluar, `resultados` almacena la salida correspondiente a cada condición de ser cierta.

Si la columna "Analisis" de algún grupo no tiene sus 5 filas correspondientes (tiene menos o más) o no cumple con ninguna de las condiciones la salida será 
`"Undetermined"` en este caso.

Comment: Excelente es lo que buscaba, ahora bien, voy a editar mi pregunta para que veas algo que necesito

Comment: Edite la respuesta.

Comment: @MartinBouhier la edición debe ser de tu pregunta, no de la respuesta, he hecho el cambio. No me queda claro cuales deben ser esas condiciones. Exactamente que salidas quieres dependiendo de cada posible combinación: `["Incremento,", "Incremento", "Incremento"]`/ `["Incremento,", "Alerta", "Incremento"]`/` `["Incremento", "Estable", "Estable"]`/ `["Estable", "Estable", "Estable"]`/`["Estable", "Estable", "Incremento"]`, etc

Comment: Perdon por la edicion. Quiero una funcion que me permita poner las condiciones como esta :
 `["Incremento,", "Alerta", "Incremento","Incremento","Estable"]`. Si esta condicion se cumple en A por ejemplo quiero que `df["Status"] = 'Critico'`. Me explico?

Comment: ¿Sería solo una condición? Es decir, si es esa es `"Crítico"` y si es cualquier otra combinación es otra cosa (dicotómico) o tendrías varias posibilidades, es decir `["Incremento,", "Alerta", "Incremento","Incremento","Estable"]` -> `"Critico"`, `["Incremento,", "Alerta", "Estable","Estable","Estable"]` -> `"Alerta"` ,  `["Estable,", "Alerta", "Estable","Estable","Estable"]` -> `"Estable"` y el resto que no concuerden con ninguna de las anteriores  le damos el valor de `"indeterminate"` Es solo un ejemplo para mostrar a que me refiero.

Comment: Exacto tendria varias posiblilidades! No las puse para no escribirlas aca y hacer extensa la pregunta pero son mas de 30. Con que vos me muestres como poner una yo la copio y pego la cantidad de veces que necesite

Comment: Pudiste descubrir alguna forma para hacerlo?

Comment: @MartinBouhier estuve un poco ocupado, he editado la respuesta con una posible solución. No se si es la mejor pero creo que hace lo que buscas. Mírala a ver que tal, si tienes alguna duda comenta, es importante que comprendas como funciona. Un saludo.

Comment: Espectacular, ahi estuve agregando otras condiciones y anda perfecto! Entendi todo el funcionamiento! Gracias!!!!!

Comment: No puedo guardarlo jaja, me muestra solo la ultima columna de status cuando intento con pandas: `df1= df1.to_csv('prueba1.csv', sep=',', index=False)`

Comment: Jajaja... @MartinBouhier quita el argumento `index`: `df1.to_csv('prueba1.csv', sep=',')`

Comment: Gracias queridooo!

Comment: Necesito agregar el valor del `ECPM_medio` >>>

Cliente Fecha Status eCPM             
AAA     27/12/2017  Crítico 0.35. Como puedo Hacerlo?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129680/agregar-valores-de-una-columna-csv-python ahi va mejor explicada la duda